# More than 1 embedded Vimeo video won't load

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo

Not the usual posting on here but I have completed an HTML page where it contains 3 embedded Vimeo videos and for some very odd reason nothing appears.

Here's the page: http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/17569_DG_mailer/www/b2c.html

First video in top section. Second video on the 2nd slide of http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/17569_DG_mailer/www/b2c.html#nav_cs2, and third video on 2nd slide of http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/17569_DG_mailer/www/b2c.html#nav_cs3

If this helps, here's my specs. Seems to be ok for Windows users.
OS: Mac OS X 10.8.2
Browser: Firefox 17.0.1

Not sure what it could possibly? The javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Would also like to add something I've discovered. If I make the browser windows width larger it appears but I'm scaling it beyond the standard monitor width.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a case - but it does not work on my Windows machine neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it will help, but documentation mentions what follow:

> If you’re embedding and controlling multiple players on a page or
>   using our JS API library (Froogaloop), you should give each player a
>   player_id that matches the id of the iframe element

Documentation:

http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

BTW, your page throws errors in several places:

```
`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/17569_DG_mailer/www/b2c.html from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/55282413. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`
```

Comment: Just gave it a try, doesn't seem to help.

I tested 3 embedded Vimeo player on a fresh HTML page with nothing else and it works fine. I've a feeling it could be in the HTML somewhere but cannot find what...

Comment: Does the same with YouTube embeds too!

Comment: Check in firebug or chrome developer toolls - you have a lot of errors there:

Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:235
extension://anlkjppofaicbdanhhpbbogknfodfhfm/getDocumentSelection.js:47
Port name deliciousBookmark chrome-extension://anlkjppofaicbdanhhpbbogknfodfhfm/getDocumentSelection.js:27
Array[2]
 chrome-extension://anlkjppofaicbdanhhpbbogknfodfhfm/getDocumentSelection.js:31

Comment: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/17569_DG_mailer/www/b2c.html from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/55282413. Domains, protocols and ports must match.